# Does the PropertyInfo.SetValue support custom implicit convertion

Tags: c#, reflection, json.net

I parse JSON response by `Newtonsoft.Json` and have a `JTokens` that I whant to dynamicly set to my model properties by custom attribute.

As I saw in the source of the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`, `JToken` have an implicit (and explicit) convertion methods for all the types that I needed but it have not inherited from `IConvertible`, so I can't use `Convert.ChangeType`.

If I will try to set them by reflection like

```
var jToken = GetJtoken(); //so I have a random JToken
var myInstance = new MyModel();
var myPropInfo = myInstance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).First();
myPropInfo.SetValue(myInstance, jToken);
```

Will that works?

Does the `PropertyInfo.SetValue` support custom implicit convertion?

If it is not, can I convert them dynamicly somehow?

Comment: `PropertyInfo.SetValue` does not support conversion via `operator` type conversion methods on the types involved. `dynamic` does, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`JToken.ToObject(Type)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject.htm) to deserialize the `jToken` to the desired type before setting the property value:

```
myPropInfo.SetValue(myInstance, jToken.ToObject(myPropInfo.PropertyType));
```

This avoids any need for implicit conversions.